# Functions in random order

Tags: vb.net, function, random

I have two functions and one for calling :

```
 Sub saystuff()
        hello1()
        hello2()
    End Sub

    Sub hello1()
        MsgBox("im number 1")
    End Sub

    Sub hello2()
        MsgBox("im number 2")
    End Sub
```

Is there a way to make those functions be done in a random order
and still doing both.

Comment: Generate a random number. if is an odd number execute hello_1 otherwise hello_2.

Comment: @Alex75, you're not wrong, but isn't that just a much less detailed version of my answer, posted 3 hours after my answer had already been accepted?

Comment: TBH, this could be done in numerous ways. Any answer given will be opinionated as there's been no attempt shown; we can't tell you where your code is wrong. Also, on another note you have some `vb6` syntax in the above code, I would recommend using `MessageBox.Show()` method.

Comment: Sorry, it's strange but when I started the Triage/First Post of this question I didn't seen the answer(s). I just put a comment to point the OP to the right way to try himself. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing anything random in .NET generally means using the `Random` class to generate a random number and then using that number in whatever way is appropriate for your application. As you only have two methods to call, I'd suggest simply testing whether the number is odd or even and then calling the methods in one order or the other.

```
Private rng As New Random

Sub SayStuff()
    If rng.Next() Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Hello1()
        Hello2()
    Else
        Hello2()
        Hello1()
    End If
End Sub

Sub Hello1()
    MsgBox("I'm number 1")
End Sub

Sub Hello2()
    MsgBox("I'm number 2")
End Sub
```

If you had more than two methods though, the number of combinations would grow quickly, so it's not really practical to do it that way.  A more general option is to create a delegate for each method, put them into a list, randomise that list and then invoke each delegate in order.

```
Private rng As New Random

Sub SayStuff()
    'Create list of delegates.
    Dim methods = {New Action(AddressOf Hello1),
                   New Action(AddressOf Hello2),
                   New Action(AddressOf Hello3)}

    'Randomise delegate list and loop through result.
    For Each method In methods.OrderBy(Function(m) rng.NextDouble())
        'Invoke current delegate.
        method()
    Next
End Sub

Sub Hello1()
    MsgBox("I'm number 1")
End Sub

Sub Hello2()
    MsgBox("I'm number 2")
End Sub

Sub Hello3()
    MsgBox("I'm number 3")
End Sub
```

You can do this no matter how many methods you want to call.  It would work with two as well.

Comment: man, i looked every where.. all i could find is the same rng, but never in functions..ur the best!

Comment: You may like to check out my edit, for interest's sake at least.

Comment: i encountered another problem, i think its simple..lets duplicate the first code, 2 callers for 4 strings.. i used two different RNGs, rng1 and rng2, they always pick same choice 2 and 2, 1 and 1 , should i use something different?

Comment: There's never a need for two `Random` objects. A single `Random` object can generate as many random numbers as you want. The fact that two instances created very quickly will generate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers is one of the main reasons to NOT use multiple instances. If you ever must use multiple instances for some reason, you need to provide a seed to the constructor and guarantee that each seed will be different.